# How to clear all things inside a loop?

Tags: function-construction, procedural-programming

It happens to me a lot when I write a loop, I have to `Clear` all functions, variables, definitions and etc to be sure my calculations is done correctly. namely as a toy example:

```
a=1;
b=2;
Do[
Clear[fun1,fun2,fun3];      
fun1[x_]:=a+bx+c;
fun2[x_]:=b+ax+c;
fun3=fun1[x]+fun2[x];
,{c,{1,4,10}}]
```

Usually I have a lot of things (similar to above funs) which must be cleared inside my loop. In fact there is a complicated algorithm inside the loop which has inner loops itself. I do one of these:

1-If I need to save loop data in a matrix for example using `Reap` and `Sow` I have to use `Clear[all things that I want to be cleared]` manually

2- If I export data loop at each stage using `Export` or `Put` I just write `` ClearAll["Global`*"] `` at the first of my loop. However most of time 1 is the case and it's a very time-consuming to clear all things manually. So I look for a way for clearing all things inside loop without clearing things outside it. Or it is better to ask: how can I use `` ClearAll["Global`*"] `` but exclude a few functions? Any idea?

Comment: You'll have to give us example code, as simple as possible, for how the problem arises. It simply doesn't happen for most of us. There's something about *Mathematica* that you're fighting rather than using.

Comment: but they are about ~60
functions which I had to define respectively

Comment: Why are you doing it this way, going back around and redefining functions, using them , then clearing them in a loop, all just to change parameters? This is inefficient - you should define your functions once and use the arguments from the call-site to change the behaviour. For example, in your code you should have `fun1[x_,c_]:=...`, `fun2[x_,c_]:=...` defined once, instead of the loop and redefinitions. That way you can easily call `fun3=Table[fun1[x,c]+fun2[x,c], {c,1,4,10}]`

Comment: In general, functions should use only the arguments provided to return an output result and not depend on variables external to the definition. Use `Module` to limit scope of variables.

Comment: Something like `funlist = {fun1,fun2,...fun60}; Do[Clear@@funlist;...]`, if `fun..` does not evaluate to something else. Otherwise, you could define them in a separate context and clear the context.

Comment: Thanks you all, but I think that I can't convey my mean unfortunately. Also I can't make a simple example like my real problem.

Comment: Perhaps the reason you can't make a simple  example is that your approach is unnecessarily complex. You *can* imitate FORTRAN in *Mathematica*, but it's tricky, as you're finding. However, *Mathematica* codes can be remarkably simple when you use the tools as intended. What is your actual problem?

Comment: If you want to try again, I would point out that in your MWE, there is no need to `Clear` the previous definitions. It makes it harder to imagine a situation in which you would.

Comment: The comment of @flinty is very relevant. It is unconventional to define and clear definitions in a loop. If it needs to be done, then it is against the very idea of a function, module, etc. They should be re-usable not one time objects.

Comment: Put everything what you have in the loop into a module.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would write your example, in a way that "jibes" with Mathematica.

```
(* Define the functions in terms of parameters *)
fun1[a_, b_][c_][x_] := a + b x + c
fun2[a_, b_][c_][x_] := b + a x + c
fun3[a_, b_][c_][x_] := fun1[a, b][c][x] + fun2[a, b][c][x]

(* Specify the parameters' values *)
a = 1; b = 2; c = {1, 4, 10};

(* Rather than loop, map across c *)
Through[(fun3[a, b] /@ c)@x]

(* Result *)
{5 + 3 x, 11 + 3 x, 23 + 3 x}
```